# Is Edittext With Hint AND Default Value Possible?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, default, hint

I am creating a tip calculator app and I was wondering how I could allow my edittext (user enters bill amount) to still display the hint (hint says "Enter Bill Amount") but also internally have a default value of zero. The reason I would like to do this is because if they press the calculate tip buttons and there is no text inputted in the edittext the app force closes, and I think with a default value of zero that would solve my problems because it would just say tip $0.00. Alternatively if somebody could advise me on how to make a pop-up saying they need to enter a bill amount that would be even better!

Current Main Java:

```
    package com.rockdrummer.calculating.calculating;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import java.text.NumberFormat;
    import java.util.Locale;


    public class MainScreen extends Activity {
        private static final NumberFormat currencyFormat= NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

        Button ten, fifteen, twenty;
        TextView tip;
        EditText bill_amount;
        double a = 0;
        double b;
        double af = 0;
        double bf;
        double ac = 0;
        double bc;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
    initControls();
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);




}



protected void initControls() {
    ten = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bTen);
    fifteen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bFifteen);
    twenty = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bTwenty);
    tip = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tip);
    bill_amount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bill);






    ten.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View ten) {


            try {
                calculate();
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    fifteen.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View fifteen) {
            try {
                calculate_f();
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    twenty.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View twenty) {
            try {
                calculate_t();
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void calculate() {


    a = 0 + Double.parseDouble(bill_amount.getText().toString());

    b = 0 + (a * 0.1);
    tip.setText("You Should Tip " + currencyFormat.format(b));
}

private void calculate_f() {
    af = 0 + Double.parseDouble(bill_amount.getText().toString());
    bf = 0 + (af * 0.15);
    tip.setText("You Should Tip " + currencyFormat.format(bf));
}

private void calculate_t() {
    ac = 0 + Double.parseDouble(bill_amount.getText().toString());
    bc = 0 + (ac * 0.20);
    tip.setText("You Should Tip " + currencyFormat.format(bc));
}
```

}

Comment: To show error message like "Please enter bill amount" you can use `Toast`. It would be better solution. Displaying hint and text at the same time is not possible by default, but even if you've managed to do it (with custom EditText) it would be a bad solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if the text is empty in your onClick/onCalculate method. If empty, use 0, ie:

```
public void onCalculate() {
    float input = 0.0;
    if (editText.getText().toString().equals("")) {
         //Text is empty do nothing
    } else {
         //parse your value
         input = Float.parseFloat(editText.getText().toString());
    }
}
```